# Why are CSS Grid-Area ending coordinates offset?

Tags: css-grid

In this [Jsbin example](https://jsbin.com/kelazet/edit?html,css,output) the grid area begins at row 1, column 1 and ends at row 3, column 2.

However in the CSS the grid-area is coded as follows:

```
grid-area: 1 / 1 / 4 / 3;
```

While the beginning coordinates (e.g. "`1 / 1`") are not offset, the second ones are (e.g. instead of being "`3 / 2`" they are "`4 / 3`").

Is there a reason why the second coordinates are offset but the first ones are not?

Here also is the markup in the above JsBin:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <style>
    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 10vh);
      grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 10vh);
      grid-gap: 13px;
      background-color: black;
      padding: 2px;
      justify-content: center;

    }

    .grid-container>div {
      background-color: aqua;
      /*rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);*/
      text-align: center;
      padding: 20px 0;
      font-size: 30px;
    }

    .item1 {
      grid-area: 1 / 1 / 4 / 3;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="item1">1</div>
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class=""></div>

    <div class=""></div>
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class=""></div>

    <div class=""></div>
    <div class=""></div>
    <div class=""></div>


  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Part of what I'm asking is whether the CSS syntax lacks integrity.  From a lay eye it appears to since the beginning coordinates are not offset while the ending coordinates are.  But perhaps there is some other sense in which the syntax is consistent/coherent?  Does anyone know why this part of the CSS syntax was designed this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Because the "offset" is, in fact, no such thing.

The numbers related to the grid**lines**; so column1 starts at 1 ends at 2, column2 starts at 2 ends at 3 and so on.

Each row/column has two lines, a *start* number and an *end* number...e.g. `grid-row-start` and `grid-row-end`.

Clearly `end` must be larger than `start` or there would be nothing in between...hence the "offset" you refer to.

Example image..

[image]

```
grid-area: 1 / 1 / 4 / 3;
```

is functionally..

```
grid-row-start: 1;
grid-column-start: 1;
grid-row-end: 4; /* end of row 3 */
grid-column-end: 3; /* end of column 2 */
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly the explanation I was looking for. Good to know that the coordinates are referring to the grid lines and not the area between the lines.  Perhaps you can answer another question?  Why does the first number refer to the row line and the second to the column line?  In other contexts coordinates are defined first by x and then by y.  But here they seem to be reversed (row [y] and then column [x] instead of column [x] and then row [y])

Comment: Thinking about it some more maybe the answer to my comment question is that it's better to think of those number pairs strictly as entities that are describing particular grid lines and not as coordinates (which describe points or intersections between lines.)  Otherwise the syntax seems counterintuitive

Comment: This article which shows how to make a bar chart with CSS-Grid also details how grid-lines work in css-grid:  https://css-tricks.com/making-a-bar-chart-with-css-grid/