# How Do I layout this CSS grids template

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, css-grid

I want to use CSS grids to display this page in the following way :

[image]

Im aware theres only 3 divs here but I want a start. how do u get div 2 and div 3 to be on the second row and on column 2 and 3. Would I need 4 total columns or 3 ?

what i got so far:

```
.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    gap: 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 
}
 .feature-one{
        grid-template-columns: 1/2;
    
  }
  .feature-two{
    grid-column: 3/6;
    grid-row: 2;
}
.feature-three{
    grid-column: 3/6;
    grid-row: 2;
}
```

this is the result of what i had:
[image]

Comment: Could you also provide your HTML code for us to have a working example to start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 30vw);
      grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
      grid-gap: 13px;
      padding: 2px;
    }

    .grid-container>div {
      background-color: aqua;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 15px;
    }

    .the-feed {
      grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 1;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="the-feed">The Feed</div>
    <div class="">Contact Lifecycle</div>
    <div class="">Custom Fields</div>
    <div class="">Custom Sales Activities</div>
    <div class="">Multi-Currency</div>
  </div>
```

Your layout is 3 columns that span the entire width of the screen.  You can define the columns like so:

```
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 30vw);
```

In addition, there are two rows of equal height.  You can define the rows like so:

```
grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
```

(If you wanted that second row to be higher than the first you could modify the above code to, say,: grid-template-rows: 100px 150px;)

Then, to make the biggest div span down across two rows you have this line:

```
.the-feed {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 1;
}
```

The above syntax can be difficult to parse at first. What it means is start the div at the gridline-row 1 and gridline-column 1 (e.g. 1/1).  And end the div at gridline-row 3 and gridline-column 1 (e.g. 3/1).

*Note that the gridlines are the lines between the columns and rows.  They are NOT the actual columns and/or rows.  To that point, a tic-tac-toe CSS-grid has 3 rows and 3 columns.  But it has 4 row-grid-lines and 4 column-grid-lines. See [Why are CSS Grid-Area ending coordinates offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61706043/why-are-css-grid-area-ending-coordinates-offset.)*

Comment: than you so much! one question. How can I make this scalable? when i add divs and h2 into it, they come out the divs.

Comment: I haven't had time to try it. But try this: grid-template-rows: 30vh 30vh;  or this: grid-template-rows: auto auto;  The former will give you rows that are 30 percent of the viewport height.  The latter (I believe) will grow to accommodate whatever content is in the div.  Caveat emptor!

Comment: Yep.  Looks like you want to use: grid-template-rows: auto auto;

Comment: appreciate it bro! you're a star. have a great day luke!

Comment: and to make it mobile responsive, its just a matter of changing the order of the grid right?

Comment: Yes.  For mobile you could add a media query and inside of it restyle the grid-template-column selector so it's only one column instead of three.  You probably will also have to restyle the .the-feed selector so its 1/1/2/2.  This should make everything stack in one column.  I haven't tested that solution so I dont know for sure.  Tinker with the css and see what works!  Oh.  You might also have to add more auto values to the row selector since you will have five rows instead of just two.

Comment: Ok. This is the last comment as S.O. is suggesting further correspondence be moved to chat. Try this:  https://jsbin.com/ruriziz/edit?html,css,output